# Tool to extract the sequence of Method or Event calls for .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When i run the application i need to extract the information about the sequence of methods or classes the application touches when any event is performed on the application.

Is any there other tool other than profiler?

Comment: Can you describe what the profiler is or isn't doing that makes it a poor choice for what you require?

Answer (score 1):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) can show the sequence of all method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "profiler"... Above the standard tools shipping with VS, Red Gate [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CK68877XiKQCFQ9qgwodIks2Iw) does a good job. There is a trial. I've used it in the past to help get a clear profile of what is being called when.

Also, if you're looking for a static analysis based on code instead of a runtime analysis, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can help a lot.

Comment: I have come to assume that when people say "profiler" they're referring to http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/ - but, you know what they say about assuming....